# How to indent text in a uitextview/nstext view using UIKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

How might I indent or un-indent text within a UITextView/NSTextView?

My code currently:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        textView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

I would like to make sure that the indented text will copy with the indent, so the user will have the ability to paste the text with the indent.

Comment: `Ident`, that's possible with if you want a tab indent with `\t`. Add it before if needed in your text, and remove it if needed. If it's just for UI, you can use `textContainer.exclusionPaths`. This won't change the text. Else, you can use `NSAttributedString`, and use `NSParagraphStyle`. For copy/pasting, first and third solution should be used then.

Comment: @Larme Thank you.  What would I do if I have text with lots of spaces before it and want to remove an indent (please note that my text does not have any \t yet)?

Comment: @Larme Maybe we can remove all spaces before the text in my uitextview.  Would you happen to know how this might be done?

Comment: Trimming with whitespaces will remove all white spaces at the beggining and the end of the string if that’s what you want...